# Como igual los colores en flutter

Tags: flutter

Haciendo uso de la herramienta Material Desing, en especifico Material Theme Builder

Hice uso de estos valores primarios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Exporte el valor de los temas y estoy haciendo uso de los mismos pero quiero igual el color de las cards, estuve investigando acerca de cual era uno de los colores y como aplicarlos de la paleta que me proporciono que fue esta:

```
final ColorScheme darkColorScheme = const ColorScheme.dark(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    primary: Color(0xFF7FD0FF),
    onPrimary: Color(0xFF00344A),
    primaryContainer: Color(0xFF004C6A),
    onPrimaryContainer: Color(0xFFC5E7FF),
    secondary: Color(0xFFB6C9D8),
    onSecondary: Color(0xFF20333E),
    secondaryContainer: Color(0xFF374955),
    onSecondaryContainer: Color(0xFFD2E5F4),
    tertiary: Color(0xFFCBC1E9),
    onTertiary: Color(0xFF332C4C),
    tertiaryContainer: Color(0xFF494263),
    onTertiaryContainer: Color(0xFFE7DEFF),
    error: Color(0xFFFFB4AB),
    errorContainer: Color(0xFF93000A),
    onError: Color(0xFF690005),
    onErrorContainer: Color(0xFFFFDAD6),
    background: Color(0xFF191C1E),
    onBackground: Color(0xFFE1E2E5),
    surface: Color(0xFF191C1E),
    onSurface: Color(0xFFE1E2E5),
    surfaceVariant: Color(0xFF41484D),
    onSurfaceVariant: Color(0xFFC1C7CE),
    outline: Color(0xFF8B9297),
    onInverseSurface: Color(0xFF191C1E),
    inverseSurface: Color(0xFFE1E2E5),
    inversePrimary: Color(0xFF00658C),
    shadow: Color(0xFF000000),
    surfaceTint: Color(0xFF7FD0FF),
    outlineVariant: Color(0xFF41484D),
    scrim: Color(0xFF000000),
  );
```

Pero al querer igualar el color en una card lo empecé a realizar de la siguiente manera

```
Material(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    shadowColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.shadow,
    surfaceTintColor: Theme.of(context) .colorScheme .inversePrimary .withOpacity(0.1),
    color: Theme.of(context) .colorScheme .primary .withOpacity(0.1),
    type: MaterialType.card,
    elevation: 5.0,
    child: const SizedBox(width: double.infinity,
        height: 100,
        child: Center(child: Text('Material3 Card Elevation'),
        ),
    ),
)
```

Tratando de igual a

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo me pude acercar al siguiente resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como podría acercarme al color que necesito? o ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambia de dos colores de la siguiente manera

```
final ColorScheme darkColorScheme = const ColorScheme.dark(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    primary: Color(0xff1E2629), //cambio de color
    onPrimary: Color(0xFF00344A),
    primaryContainer: Color(0xFF004C6A),
    onPrimaryContainer: Color(0xFFC5E7FF),
    secondary: Color(0xFFB6C9D8),
    onSecondary: Color(0xFF20333E),
    secondaryContainer: Color(0xFF374955),
    onSecondaryContainer: Color(0xFFD2E5F4),
    tertiary: Color(0xFFCBC1E9),
    onTertiary: Color(0xFF332C4C),
    tertiaryContainer: Color(0xFF494263),
    onTertiaryContainer: Color(0xFFE7DEFF),
    error: Color(0xFFFFB4AB),
    errorContainer: Color(0xFF93000A),
    onError: Color(0xFF690005),
    onErrorContainer: Color(0xFFFFDAD6),
    background: Color(0xFF191C1E), //cambio de color
    onBackground: Color(0xFFE1E2E5),
    surface: Color(0xFF191C1E),
    onSurface: Color(0xFFE1E2E5),
    surfaceVariant: Color(0xFF41484D),
    onSurfaceVariant: Color(0xFFC1C7CE),
    outline: Color(0xFF8B9297),
    onInverseSurface: Color(0xFF191C1E),
    inverseSurface: Color(0xFFE1E2E5),
    inversePrimary: Color(0xFF00658C),
    shadow: Color(0xFF000000),
    surfaceTint: Color(0xFF7FD0FF),
    outlineVariant: Color(0xFF41484D),
    scrim: Color(0xFF000000),
  );
```

Y en tu color de objeto una opacidad de 1

```
Material(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    shadowColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.shadow,
    surfaceTintColor: Theme.of(context) .colorScheme .inversePrimary .withOpacity(0.1),

    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(1),//Opacidad a 1

    type: MaterialType.card,
    elevation: 5.0,
    child: const SizedBox(width: double.infinity,
        height: 100,
        child: Center(child: Text('Material3 Card Elevation'),
        ),
    ),
)
```

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ah de ser también desde el monitor que la veo porque si ya se esta igualando